# Omnet++: Module Error: Ephemeral port range 1024..5000 exhausted

Tags: tcp, omnet++, inet

I am doing simulation on datacenter network. I use inet TCPBasicClientApp module for TCP traffic. In my simulation, I feed a set of TCP flows from a file. It works for most of the tests, but in some tests I got the error: 
**Module Error: Ephemeral port range 1024..5000 exhausted**
I tried to figure out, but it seems out of my control, because this error comes from Inet TCP module. 
After digging up Google, I got an idea that the error is related to 2 parameters: 
thinkTime 
idleInterval

They said as soon as they increased them, the problem is solved.

I was setting both at 1s; then tried to increase it to 2s, and 5s for both parameters, but the error still remains.

So is there anyone has faced this error and got rid of it, or has any idea to fix this error just share me please? I very much appreciate any help.

Best,

Danh

---

Hi all, let me update my solution for this problem, in case someone need to refer. So instead of using ephemeral local port which is limited in a range (1024--5000), I use normal port number by setting the parameter localPort, with initial value of 2000 then increases by 1 for every new socket. By setting that I don't see the error anymore, so I guess my simulation now can serve as much as the maximum port number supported in Omnet, e.g, 65535 ports. Thanks.

Best,

Danh

Comment: Could you show `TCPApp` setting from your `omnetpp.ini`?

Comment: @Jezy, I make my own TCPTrafficGenerator module by extending the TCPBasicClientApp, and feed my module from a flows file in C++ code, via TCPSocket, so in omnetpp.ini I just specify the filename, and a couple of setttings like this: 
`**.numTcpApps = 2
**.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPTrafficGenerator"
**.tcpApp[1].typename = "StatSink"
**.thinkTime = 2s
**.idleInterval = 2s
`
I realize the problem occurs when a node send too many sessions (close to 3000 flows) to other nodes. So I should dig into my C++ code, may be I didn't close connections whenever it completes.

Comment: Hi all, let me update my solution for this problem. So instead of using ephemeral local port which is limited in a range (1024--5000), I use normal port number by setting the parameter localPort, with initial value of 2000 then increases by 1 for every new socket. By setting that I don't see the error anymore, so I guess my simulation now can serve as much as the maximum port number supported in Omnet, e.g, 65535 ports. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I had de same problem but after setting -as you mention- both `app[0].thinkTime = 1s` and `app[0].idleInterval = 1s` the problem is gone. I'm using omnet++ 5.4.1. The simulation time is 1000s. I'll keep an eye on this an let you know ...